# iOS: detailViewConroller not actualized

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, storyboard

i have problem with making iOS application.
I use the newest SDKs, and storyboard with tableView. If I testing app on ipad it is OK, but on iphone detailviewcontroler is not actualized.

my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)sender didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    self.detailViewController.title = [[self.items objectAtIndex:path.row] title];
    [self.detailViewController.detailWebView loadHTMLString:[[self.items objectAtIndex:path.row] content] baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
}
```

I controlled everything with ipad storyboard and references are the same.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

before using property of any class you have initialize its class first, so try this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)sender didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {

self.detailViewController =[[DetailViewController alloc]init]; 

self.detailViewController.title = [[self.items objectAtIndex:path.row] title];

[self.detailViewController.detailWebView loadHTMLString:[[self.items objectAtIndex:path.row] content] baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];

 }
```

here i assume that you class name is DetailViewController

Comment: I added initilazation and it not solve problem. And in ipad is detail empty too now :(

Comment: try this    if (! DetailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    }
    self.detailViewController=[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AllVideosViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

Comment: no change :( still not working (I replace AllVideosViewController with my identifier ofcourse). it is like I dont have reference to detailViewController, but it is interesting that in ipad it works

Comment: to Desai Ajay: can you write me an email on macro007@gmail.com, because I am at the end of my nerves :(